# vincular una opcion de select con un checkbox . C# MVC

Tags: javascript, html, c#, mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

vengo con ustedes ya que quisiera saber como hacer lo siguiente.

En esta tabla:
[image]

cuando Selecciono el checkbox genero un arreglo para guardar el valor de los checkbox seleccionados, el detalle es que necesito poder vincular el valor del select con el valor de checkbox para poder relacionarlos en la base de datos y restarselos a los "Pax por asignar".

en codigo del select es el siguiente

```
<select class="form-control">
                        @{
                            <option>Seleccione</option>
                            for (int i = 1; i <= item.Pax_por_asignar; i++)
                            {
                                <option value="@i" class="opt">@i</option>
                            }
                        }
                    </select>
```

entonces como podria generar vincular ambos o hacer que el javascript lea ambos valores y los coloque juntos en un JSON o algo por el estilo.

espero puedan ayudarme, muchas gracias

**EDIT: Codigo javascript que utilizo para tomar el valor del checkbox**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#asig').on('click', function () {
        var url = **********************;
        var Jids = [];
        $('.ckbox:checked').each(function () {
            Jids.push(parseInt($(this).val()));
        });
        var formData = {
            Cid: Jids
        };
        $.post(url, formData);
    });

});
```

Comment: Estas usando jQuery o no?

Comment: ¿Has visto los HTML helpers?

Comment: estoy usando javascript

Comment: madre de dios, que codigo tan horrible, donde esta el objeto con Id "#asig" ?, para que realizas el post ? 
por que estas usando un select y no haces una lista de checkboxes ? editado: ya vi por que... razor... , cambia tu select a una lista de checkboxes, puedes hacerlo si les das el mismo nombre a cada checkbox pero diferente ID

Comment: Que relacion tiene el CheckBox con el select? O solo quieres recoger el valor del select y el valor del checkbox?

Comment: el checkbox me trae el Id del booking en la base de datos, la razon por la que quiero poder relacionar el valor que escogi en el select con el id de esta fila es para poder restarle el valor a "Pax por asignar" y en la tabla mostrar solo lo que me falta por asignar

Comment: @PedroLuisSC ¿porque no guardas el texto en una columna invisible? Quizás soy yo el que no entiendo, pero por lo que interpreto el checkbox es completamente innecesario

Comment: el motivo es el siguiente, necesito poder vincular el valor seleccionado con el ID que esta en el checkbox esto para poder restarselo al campo "Pax por asignar" ya que cuando este campo sea 0 no deberia mostrar el registro en la tabla @JuanSalvadorPortugal la necesidad del checkbox es que con este obtengo el ID y utilizo este ID para otro tanto de operaciones en mi controlador pero no tengo problema alguno con ellas